# How to unroot and remove a custom kernal on android

Tags: factory-reset, kernel, unrooting

I have had my Samsung s5 mini (G800F) for some time now and am looking to sell it. I rooted the phone and used a custom kernal that allowed OTG support for the phone.

How do I remove the root and the kernal to the absolute original state?

(very simple instructions would be helpful - I'm a noob with android :D)

Comment: How did you root it and flashed the custom kernel at first place?

Comment: @Firelord I used ODIN, and this kernal: http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5-mini/orig-development/kernel-custom-kernel-t3130662

Comment: I'd say by flashing a stock ROM. Cannot give any instructions for that, but you've already named the tool for this: Odin.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing you did with Odin when you flashed the custom firmware. Just download your phone's firmware from http://samsung-updates.com/latest-firmware/ and flash everything in the downloaded files.

Comment: Looks like the link is dead?